# Jmeter: Parallelly running Thread Group execution gets delayed

Tags: jmeter

I have 3 Thread Groups: Setup Thread Group, Thread Group 2(which has the http request which does the download of the file), Thread Group 3 under a single Test Plan. The thread count=3 for each. The checkbox 'Run consecutively' is deselected in the Test plan.

The Setup thread group has all the pre-requisite requests which are needed to be executed prior to Thread Group 2 and 3. The Setup Thread Group(having multiple https requests) writes some authentication tokens to 2 different csv files which will then be utilized by the other 2 thread groups respectively when they get executed in parallel at later point of time. So, csv file1 will be used by Thread Group 2 and csv file2 will be used by Thread Group 3.

First, the Setup Thread Group gets executed.Then the Thread Group 2 and Thread Group 3 get executed in parallel. Everything seems fine when all of the threads of Setup Thread Group get the successful response:200.

But when there is any erroneous response like 500 in one of the Setup Thread Group thread Response, the csv files get less number of entries(which is fine); and the Thread Group 2 and Thread Group 3 do not run in parallel. The Thread group 3 runs first. Then after some time gap, the Thread group 2 runs. What's the cause and resolution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

1) Set Up Thread: Extract the response code or any response message of the Last sampler of the Set Up Thread.
2) Before proceeding Thread group 2 or 3 add some constant time and a BSF pre-processor. validate the condition of the extracted value(either response code/response message).
If the anticipated value is found, proceed with Thread group 2 and 3.
If not Add some constant time within the BSF(define a condition).
3) do the simlar approach, to wait for Thread Group-3 to ensure Thread Group-2 has ran succesfully.